# Table-based custom type does not verify check constraints

Tags: postgresql, composite-types, check-constraints

Is there any way for a table-based custom type to obey the table check constraints, other than creating my own type based on the table?

Assume the following table that serves as a source for the custom type:

```
CREATE TABLE source
(
  id character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  weight smallint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT source_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT source_weight_check CHECK (weight > 0 AND weight < 6)
)
```

Now, I intend to create the following data table:

```
CREATE TABLE final
(
  name character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  data source NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT final_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name),
)
```

**When inserting records** into the *final* table, **the check constraint will not be observed**.

**Requirements:**

1. I'd like to avoid creating my own type based of source, because when
   source changes I'll be forced to remember to also update the custom
   type.
2. I realize that table-based custom types obey domain check constraints. But, on my particular case, the weight field in the *source* database is ill-suited for a domain. Its check constraints varies from table to table. FYI, it's a value used in calculating weighted averages.

Comment: Why not simply use a plain foreign key instead of defining a table as the attribute of another table (I didn't even know this was possible).

Comment: The data field in the final table is just a composite field that shares the structure of the source table. It has no link with the source table. In Postgres any table definition is a data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A record will only be null if **all** of its fields are null or if the record itself is null. If you want to check if any of the fields is null then check one by one:

```
create table final
(
    name character varying(20) not null,
    data source check (
        (data).id is not null and (data).weight is not null
    ),
    constraint final_pkey primary key (name)
);

insert into final (name, data) values ('a', null);
ERROR:  new row for relation "final" violates check constraint "final_data_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (a, null).

insert into final (name, data) values ('a', (null, null));
ERROR:  new row for relation "final" violates check constraint "final_data_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (a, (,)).

insert into final (name, data) values ('a', ('1', null));
ERROR:  new row for relation "final" violates check constraint "final_data_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (a, (1,)).

insert into final (name, data) values ('a', ('1', 1));
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: So essentially I need to replicate the check constraint on the table that includes the composite type?